# How to create custom ActivationPolicy of the app?

Tags: swift, nswindow, menubar, dock

Original activation policies is:

```
// The application is an ordinary app that appears in the Dock and may
// have a user interface.
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)

// The application does not appear in the Dock and does not have a menu
// bar, but it may be activated programmatically or by clicking on one
// of its windows.
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)

// The application does not appear in the Dock and may not create
// windows or be activated.
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.prohibited)
```

I need combination of all of those policies:

- to display icon in dock  like `.regular`
- to do not have menubar like `.acessory`
- [resolved] to display window above fullscreen apps like `.prohibited`
- [resolved] to register window notifications like in `.regular` and `.acessory`
- [resolved] to have ability to open "Preferences" window like in .regular and .acessory---

How can I create own ActivationPolicy or how can I controll those parameters without "policy" ?

upd: part of problems resolved here:
[How to locate window over all of apps (even if they are fullscreen-ed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518709/how-to-locate-window-over-all-of-apps-even-if-they-are-fullscreen-ed)